Animación de despliegue de un sidebar
Estoy haciendo una animación para que el despliegue de la sidebar se vea normal. El tema está en que los iconos aparecen cuando la sidebar está sin desplegar y que cuando se despliegue la animación sea natural.
He probado de todo pero usando opacity en .overTxt se me queda una hueco, y usando la animación directamente en la sidebar la sidebar se mueve hacia la derecha en vez de desplegase el texto.


function hoverSidebar() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar .overTxt');
  let sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

  sidebar.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('overTxt'));
  });

  sidebar.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.add('overTxt'));
  });
}

hoverSidebar();
nav .sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

nav .sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

nav .sidebar li {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  display: flex;
}

nav .sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

nav .sidebar a {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}

nav .sidebar a p {
  margin: -5px 10px;
}

nav .sidebar .selected {
  background-color: #3142c4;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

nav .sidebar .selected:hover {
  background-color: #3142c4;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.overTxt {
  display: none;
}
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0-beta1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <a href="">
      <li class="selected"><i class="fa-solid fa-table-columns"></i>
        <p class="overTxt">Panel de control</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li><i class="fa-regular fa-life-ring"></i>
        <p class="overTxt" id="overTxt">Soporte</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i>
        <p class="overTxt">Estado servicio</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        <p class="overTxt">Nuevo Servicio</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
        <p class="overTxt">Opciones</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>



PD: Los etiquetas i son para los iconos de la librería font awesome.

¿A qué te refieres con "la animación sea natural"? Eso puede significar diferentes cosas para diferentes personas. Da más detalles que expliquen qué es lo que quieres que ocurra y cuándo. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio (y de ese modo conseguirás una nueva medalla).

El hueco que se queda es porque estás usando un elemento <p> que se mostrará como un bloque, si lo remplazas con un <span>, que se mostrará en línea, ya no hay hueco y se ve más "natural". Pero no sé si es eso a lo que te refieres.

Si quieres que no aparezcan los íconos cuando el mouse está afuera del menú, debes declararlos de la misma clave "overText" que estás usando para los textos. De dejo un ejemplo y, de paso, declaro un rectángulo visible para saber dónde hay que pasar el mouse para activar el menú.


function hoverSidebar() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar .overTxt');
  let sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

  sidebar.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('overTxt'));
  });

  sidebar.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.add('overTxt'));
  });
}

hoverSidebar();
nav .sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

nav .sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

nav .sidebar li {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  display: flex;
}

nav .sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

nav .sidebar a {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}

nav .sidebar a p {
  margin: -5px 10px;
}

nav .sidebar .selected {
  background-color: #3142c4;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

nav .sidebar .selected:hover {
  background-color: #3142c4;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.overTxt {
  display: none;
}
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0-beta1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sidebar" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <ul>
    <a href="">
      <li class="overTxt selected"><i class="fa-solid fa-table-columns"></i>
          &nbsp;Panel de control 
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="overTxt"><i class="fa-regular fa-life-ring"></i>
        &nbsp;Soporte
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="overTxt"><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i>
        &nbsp;Estado servicio
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="overTxt"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        &nbsp;Nuevo Servicio
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="overTxt"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
        Opciones
      </li>
    </a>

  </ul>
</div>




Creo que no es esto lo que busca. Parece que quiere que los iconos estén siempre disponibles y que sea sólo el texto lo que se muestre al pasar el ratón por encima. La pregunta no es clara y no especifica bien qué es lo que se está buscando.
